# ruby on rails installing JSON ubuntu error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Hey I am new to rails (as well as linux) and I keep getting this error:

```
Installing json (1.7.5) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb 
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file  -- mkmf (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /home/jack/.bundler/tmp/10426/gems/json-1.7.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/jack/.bundler/tmp/10426/gems/json-1.7.5/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.7.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.5'` succeeds before bundling.
jack@jack-ThinkCentre:~/rails_projects/sample_app$
```

I cant install the gem individually or with bundle install. I used rvm to install rails. thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens when you try 'gem install json' separately?

Comment: Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing json:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
 from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


    Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5 for inspection.
    Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out

Comment: Is this the first time using rails? What's ur OS? If OSX: What XCode version do u have (xcodebuild -version)?

Comment: Try upgrading your Ruby and reinstalling gems.

Comment: I get this error:   Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
 from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out

Comment: @polarblau what are you talking about?

Comment: How do you do that? I don't see a button to do that?

Comment: Go to your account page. / Open a question you had previously asked. / See if someone has provided an answer which solved your problem. / Accept this answer by clicking the green checkmark beneath the votes counter on the left side to the answer. (— Please familiarize yourself a bit with how SO works before you carry on. Cheers!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Installing the ruby1.9.1-dev package should fix this for you**

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

"The same issue on ubuntu-trusty-64 running ruby 2.2.3. the solution is to install libgmp3-dev."

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```