# error installing rails ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ruby on rails installing JSON ubuntu error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652788/ruby-on-rails-installing-json-ubuntu-error)

I get this error when I try installing rails on ubuntu:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file --  mkmf (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

I used rvm to install. I don't know why it keeps happening

Comment: Isn't this the same problem you reported an hour ago in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652788/ruby-on-rails-installing-json-ubuntu-error ? -- please close this and edit the original question.

Comment: it says aptitude command not found. @tom that was for Json... I guess my whole installation is wrong though